# Simultaneously fit two linear functions with a single slope

Tags: python, statistics

I have two sets of experimental data, as shown on the figure [image: figure]
For [image: x = 0] the measured data must be the same for the two sets. Therefore, I would like to fit both sets simultaneously, defining a single y-intercept and two slopes. As far as I understand, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48674558/how-to-implement-automatic-model-determination-and-two-state-model-fitting-in-py) does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are going to do a [simple linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression). The problem here is to minimize the error for two linear functions with identical interception. The error function is:

```
def f(params):
    alpha, betha_1, betha_2 = params
    e_1 = np.power(y1- alpha - (betha_1 * x),2)
    e_2 = np.power(y2- alpha - (betha_2 * x),2)
    error = np.sum(e_1 + e_2)
    return error
```

I used `scipy.optimize.minimize` to get optimum parameters. The final code is:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y2 = [9, 11, 10, 12, 13, 12, 12]
y1 = [10, 12, 11, 12, 12, 13, 14]
x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
x, y1, y2 = np.array(x), np.array(y1), np.array(y2)

def f(params):
    alpha, betha_1, betha_2 = params
    e_1 = np.power(y1- alpha - (betha_1 * x),2)
    e_2 = np.power(y2- alpha - (betha_2 * x),2)
    error = np.sum(e_1 + e_2)
    return error

initial_guess = [1, 1, 1]
result = minimize(f, initial_guess)

xfine = np.arange(0, 6, 0.001)
y1_reg = result.x[0] + result.x[1]*xfine
y2_reg = result.x[0] + result.x[2]*xfine

plt.plot(x, y1, 'bo', x, y2, 'go', xfine, y1_reg, 'b', xfine, y2_reg, 'g')
plt.show()
```

and the result:
[image: Liear Regression Result]